# Getting an error while creating database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to create database using rake db:create I am getting the following error

```
** Invoke db:create (first_time)

** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)

** Invoke rails_env (first_time)

** Execute rails_env

** Execute db:load_config

** Execute db:create

rake aborted!

undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/railties
/databases.rake:32:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'


/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'

/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'

/usr/bin/rake:23:in `load'

/usr/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
```

I have checked My database.yml file and it is empty.I am new to JRuby. I am using the following list of gems in my project and it shows that there are two databases are there one is pg and other is sqlite that are used with  ActiveRecord-JDBC adapter.My gem file looks like :

```
gem 'rails', '~>3.0.10'
gem 'builder', '~> 2.1.2'    
gem 'exception_notification', '~> 2.5.2'
gem 'rubyzip', :require => 'zip/zip'
gem 'haml', '3.1.3'                  #, :git => 'git://github.com/nex3/haml.git'
gem 'sass', '3.1.7'                  #, :git => 'git://github.com/nex3/haml.git'
gem 'compass', '0.11.5'              #, :git => 'git://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git'
gem 'formtastic', '2.0.0.rc4'        #, :git => 'git://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic.git'
gem 'inherited_resources', '1.3.0   ' #, :git => 'git://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources.git'
gem 'simple-navigation', '3.5.0'     #, :git => 'git://github.com/andi/simple-navigation.git'
gem 'tabs_on_rails', '2.0.2'         #, :git => 'git://github.com/weppos/tabs_on_rails.git'
gem 'dynamic_form', '1.1.4'          #, :git => 'git://github.com/rails/dynamic_form.git'
gem 'show_for', '0.2.4'
gem 'liquid', '2.3.0'
gem 'crack'
gem 'jquery-rails', '1.0.14'
gem 'jrails', '0.6.0'
gem 'sprockets', '1.0.2'
gem 'hominid', '3.0.4'
platforms :jruby do
  gem 'ActiveRecord-JDBC', '0.5'
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter', '1.2.0'
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter', '1.2.0'
end
platforms :ruby do
  gem 'pg', '0.13.2'
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.4'
end
gem 'silent-postgres', '0.1.1'
gem 'automatic_foreign_key', '1.3.0'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'rack-ssl', :require => 'rack/ssl'
# paginators
gem 'kaminari', '~> 0.12.4'
gem 'aasm', '~> 3.0.6'
gem "meta_search", '1.0.6' #, :git => 'git://github.com/ernie/meta_search.git'
gem 'devise', '1.5.3'      #, :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'
gem 'cancan', '1.6.5'      #, :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'
gem 'nokogiri',              '1.5.0'
gem 'hpricot', '0.8.4'
gem 'jruby-rack', '1.0.10', :platforms => :jruby
gem 'rack', '1.2.3'
gem 'rack-html5', '1.0.2'
gem 'rack-html5-rails_helper', '1.0.1'
gem 'html5-boilerplate', '1.0.0'
gem 'rmagick', '2.13.1', :platforms => :ruby
gem 'rmagick4j', '0.3.7', :platforms => :jruby
gem 'jruby-openssl', '0.7.4', :platforms => :jruby
gem 'ruby_parser', '2.0.6'
gem 'delayed_job', '2.1.4', :platforms => :ruby
gem 'resque', '1.19.0', :platforms => :jruby
gem 'clockwork', '0.2.4'
gem 'stalker', '0.9.0'
gem 'meta-tags', '1.2.4', :require => 'meta_tags'
gem 'carrierwave', '0.5.7'
gem 'mini_magick', '3.3'
gem 'activemerchant', '~> 1.22.0'
gem 'xeroizer', '~> 0.4.1'
gem 'quickeebooks', :git => 'git://github.com/ruckus/quickeebooks.git'

gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'mongo_mapper'

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '2.9.0'
  gem 'capistrano-ext'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano', '~> 1.0.2'
  gem 'awesome_print', '0.4.0'
end

gem 'backup', '=3.0.22' # :git => 'git://github.com/meskyanichi/backup.git'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'roo', '1.9.7'
gem 'ffaker', '1.8.1'
gem 'ckeditor', '3.6.3'
gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'
gem 'ssl_requirement', '0.1.0'
gem 'unicorn', '4.1.1'
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Are you intentionally using an old activerecord version? (3.0)?  And why is your database.yml empty, you might try filling it with the correct values :)

Comment: Thanks Hugo for the reply but as I have said I am new with JRUBY ,I am working on someone else's code and they are using two databases as you can see in the gemfile .Regarding version They are using gem 'ActiveRecord-JDBC', '0.5'. I am using Rails 3.0.10 with ruby 1.9.2p290 ..any help??

Comment: The Gemfile contains only the 'driver' for the databases. The database.yml the connection settings and location for the databases. Like this: https://gist.github.com/961978

Comment: I have tried with sqlite but it is giving me errors that database already exist..

Comment: If it exists, then why do you want to create it?

Comment: Hey thanks Hugo I have reset the database and now it is working with SQLite .and just a quick one if using postgres do I explicitly create the database and then use database.yml or is there any easy way..

Comment: You always need to use a database.yml. It the connection settings. Your problem was trying to create a database that already existed, instead of just using (and emptying) it...